# formula field to display multi select picklist (selected values)

Tags: formula, formula-field, administration, multi-select

I have a Multi-select picklist in account object and I want to display the selected picklist values in contact object using a formula field. I came across many using multiple If conditions. In my scenario, I have 20+ values in Multi-select picklist, how am I supposed to do that

Comment: Use Case Function instead of Multiple If..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update a **contact object formula field** based on the values from the **account object multi-select picklist** . In contact formula field write down as

```
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Multi_select__c,"value"),"value;",null)&
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Multi_select__c,"value"),value;",null)&
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Multi_select__c,"value"),"value;",null)&
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Multi_select__c,"value"),"value;",null)
```

and goes on. When my formula field has more characters this is the error I faced

***The formula expression is invalid: Formula is too long (6,647 characters). Maximum length is 3,900 characters*** .
In that case, try to use trigger its a good choice.

```
  trigger accountTrigger on Account(after insert,after update) {
    List<contact>contactlst = new List<contact>();
    List<contact> cnt = new List<contact>();
    map<string,string> mapOfAccntIds =  new map<string,string>();

    for(Account act:Trigger.new){
        mapOfAccntIds.put(act.id, act.Multi_select__c);
    }

    contactlst = [select id, Multi_Select_Text__c, name, AccountId from 
                    contact where AccountId IN: mapOfAccntIds.keySet()];

    for(contact c :contactlst ){
            c.Multi_Select_Text__c= mapOfAccntIds.get(c.accountId);
            cnt.add(c);      
    }
  }  
    if(cnt != null & cnt.Size()> 0)
    upsert cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like this:

```
> IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist_1__c , "A"), "A" + BR(), NULL) + 
> IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist_1__c , "B"), "B" + BR(), NULL) + 
> IF(INCLUDES( Multi_Picklist_1__c , "C"), "C", NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5)...

> Multi-select picklist fields can only be used in these functions:
>    - INCLUDES
>    - ISBLANK
>    - ISNULL

So... if you want to stick to a formula... you are stuck with the IF-INCLUDES for each option.

You could alternative consider making a very simple trigger `on before insert and before update` on your parent object that writes the String with all the values into a String field, and put a formula linked to it on the child object.

Comment: took your advice and wrote trigger :)