# Formula to update multi-picklist with Salesforce Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, multi-select

The requirement I have is that a multi-picklist (MSP) field ("Specialty") is updated based on any additional values from another multi-picklist field ("Specialty Marketing") with the same picklist options. This means any values on field B should be ADDED (not overwritten) to the already selected values on field A. I need to do this using Salesforce Flow and although I think I got the flow right, I am not too confident about the formula which updates the "Specialty" (varSpecialtyMSPvalue) field with values from the "Specialty Marketing (newSpecialtyMSPvalue)" values.

```
IF(ISBLANK({!varSpecialtyMSPvalue}),
{!newSpecialtyMSPvalue},
IF(NOT(CONTAINS({!varSpecialtyMSPvalue},{!newSpecialtyMSPvalue})),
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({!varSpecialtyMSPvalue},'[',''),']',';'+{!newSpecialtyMSPvalue}),
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({!varSpecialtyMSPvalue},'[',''),']','')
))
```

EDIT: The formula is correct in terms of syntax as I can run the flow but the field is overwritten instead of appended (i.e. existing values are removed and new values are added).
During debug, I get the following results:

**1. Successfully found record.
{!varSpecialtyMSPvalue} = null**

**2. Update the records’ field values.
EMEA_Specialty__c = {!Update_Specialty_Field} (null)**

What am I missing? Thank you to whoever takes the time to give me guidance!

Below a snapshot of my flow elements for additional context:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! I don't have time to test things out, and I don't know if this is still the case, but at one point in formulae you needed to use `INCLUDES` rather than `CONTAINS` for multi-select picklists. (See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_includes.htm&type=5 | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/198532/81648). If your 2nd field does not have to be multi-select, and could be a formula field instead, you *might* could do this without a Flow: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322999&type=1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I need to convert the multi-picklist to text to be able to work with it in a flow, I can't use INCLUDES. Moreover, both fields need to remain a multi-picklist since I want to append additional values :)

Comment: So have you run this "as-is"? If so, what is the result: An error? Nothing? Unexpected result?

Comment: If so (and if not, please do so, and then) please edit your question to add that information.

Comment: I've edited my question accordingly - thanks!

Comment: 1) Are either or both of your picklists restricted to their value sets? 2) If so, are all values for both exactly the same?

Comment: Something does not seem right.... In your Update Specialty Field element, you populate the `Specialty__c` field with the value from your `Update_Specialty_Field` variable (which is confusing - I would suggest renaming so it does not exactly match the name of the element). What Data Type is the `Update_Specialty_Field` variable? It appears to be a Boolean or a Record or you have somehow told that element to update the field with the element itself.

Comment: But when I create a Flow Formula Variable of Data Type "Text" and plug in your formula, then use it in the last step to populate the `Specialty__c` field, I get an error because the square brackets are still there.

Comment: see if this [UnofficialSf.com component](https://unofficialsf.com/multiselect-magic-manage-multiselect-picklists-with-flow/) can be of use

Comment: It seems to me that you have way more going on behind the scenes of your Flow. If I have the `varSpecialty...` and `newSpecialty...` variables set as MSPs, or try to do the Formula directly on those fields, I get the error that CONTAINS does not work. If I have those variables set as Text, the Flow errors on the Update step due to square brackets. I'm going to pause any effort to get this to work until you update to give way more details.

Comment: @Moonpie - many thanks for those insights. I will have a closer look at the Update_Specialty_Field variable to see whether I have missed something and get back to you! Btw, I used this resource to build my flow - https://ektasingh2709.medium.com/updating-multi-select-picklist-values-adding-not-replacing-using-flow-a220ccf8c1e3

Comment: To answer some of your questions:
1) Yes, they are restricted to their value sets.
2) Yes, they are exactly the same.
3) Where in the Update Specialty Field element do you see me populating Specialty__c field with the value from your Update_Specialty_Field variable? 
4) Update_Specialty_Field variable together with the other variables are all text types, not boolean or record.

Comment: What I am confused about is why my Get Record on the Specialty__c field is resulting in a null value although there are values stored there.

Comment: *"Where in the Update Specialty Field element do you see me populating Specialty__c field with the value from your Update_Specialty_Field variable?"* Your last screen shot shows `Update_Specialty_Field` value being written to the Contact `Specialty__c` field. |  *"...variables are all text types, not boolean or record."* On that same step, the symbol associated to the `Update_Specialty_Field` variable is the one that looks like Venn diagram or two links of chain or a hurricane. Within the Flow canvas, that symbol denotes a Boolean or a Record variable; Text variables have the "Aa" symbol.

Comment: It's also the symbol for GET and UPDATE RECORDS Flow elements, and you can accidentally select one of those and it won't show an error on save - but can cause headaches. (Ask me how I know.)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, using the UPDATE RECORDS Flow elements with a simple IF(NOT(CONTAINS formula was not possible as the multi-picklist values were not parsed and thus finding a duplicate was impossible. The challenge I had was that I had two identical Multi-Select Picklist fields ('Specialty' and 'Specialty Marketing') and the objective was that whenever the field 'Specialty Marketing' gets populated with a number of picklist values, these should be ADDED to the existing values on the Specialty field and not OVERWRITTEN. This means I had to find a way to convert both Multi-Select Picklist fields into a text collection variable so I could loop through them to identify existing values vs unique ones.

Thus, I had to completely re-invent the wheel to do the following and IT WORKS:

1. [APEX Action](https://www.accidentalcodersf.com/2021/01/parse-multi-select-picklist-values-flow.html) to firstly parse the Multi Select Picklist values of both fields: takes the Multi Select Picklist values in format [A;B;C;D] and will return two separate text collection variables in format [A,B,C,D].
2. Now that I had two collection variables, I was able to loop through both items and compare them with another to identify if an item in the field 'Specialty Marketing' was existing in the field 'Specialty'.
3. For each item in the first loop, I set a Boolean variable to *'FALSE'* which I could later use to check if it was set to 'TRUE', given that a duplicate was found.
4. I then looped each item my 'Specialty Marketing' text collection variable through the 'Specialty' text collection variable and put in a decision-split which checked if the current item from loop 1 (Specialty Marketing) == current item from loop 2 (Specialty).
   If **YES** = change the Boolean variable to *TRUE* and loop through the next item.
   If **NO** = do nothing and continue to loop through the next item.
5. After the last item of loop 2, I then checked whether the Boolean field is currently set to *FALSE*.
   If **YES** = added the current item of loop 1 to a stored text variable
   (newList) where I was storing all of my unique values which I wanted
   to append to my original Multi Select Picklist (originalList) which
   I retrieved through the Apex Action and was stored in a text
   collection variable.
6. After the last item of loop 1, I then merged the (newList) with the (originalList) by adding them in an assignment element and updated the record with that assignment output.

Here's a screenshot of the flow:[image: Flow]

Comment: or - [UnOfficialSF.com MSP component](https://unofficialsf.com/multiselect-magic-manage-multiselect-picklists-with-flow/) for a more widely-used apex action